# An old Jeff Buckley('s) song

Tags: possessives

I wonder about the possessive here. If we add "'s," in my opinion, the phrase will mean that Jeff is old, not the song. However, I saw the phrase like this, without possessive, and am curious: why it's not here? Is "Jeff Buckley" part of the noun phrase? Can personal names even function like this in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *an old Jeff Buckley song* would be the normal way to say it. If you wanted to use the possessive, you'd need to say *an old song of Jeff Buckley's*.